# Restored Hyper-v machine unable to live migrate to another host in the cluster

Tags: windows, hyper-v

Migrating Hyper-v Windows servers from old cluster to new one using Veeam tool ended sucessfully.
I noticed that there is a issue with migrations.

All three hosts are new Lenovo SR650, completly the same configured.

When I tried to migrate VM created in that new cluster, migrations WORKED well, only restored machines have trouble with MOVE action, went to FAILED state, after
deleting saved state VM can be powered on on desired host but live migrations won't work without "reboot" of the machine.
I already tried CPU compatibility feature turned on, no luck.

Also, there is no ISO file mounted on the VM. All three hosts has the same network adapter name.
Hosts has Windows 2019 Standard installed, teamd 2 phy interfaces and created virtual.

The errors I get when VM went into the "failed" status are:

'Virtual Machine VM' failed to start.

'VM' failed to restore. (Virtual machine ID 1111C5E4-D163-4E84-B6BE-1F33656xxxxxxx)

The virtual machine 'VM' is not compatible with physical computer ''Host2'. (Virtual machine ID 1111C5E4-D163-4E84-B6BE-1F33656xxxxxxx)

Cluster resource 'Virtual Machine VM' of type 'Virtual Machine' in clustered role 'VM' failed. The error code was '0xc0370029' ('Cannot restore this virtual machine to the saved state because of hypervisor incompatibility. Delete the saved state data and then try to start the virtual machine.').

'Virtual Machine VM' failed to start.

'VM' failed to restore. (Virtual machine ID 1111C5E4-D163-4E84-B6BE-1F33656xxxxxxx)

The virtual machine 'VM' is not compatible with physical computer 'Host2'. (Virtual machine ID 1111C5E4-D163-4E84-B6BE-1F33656xxxxxxx)

Found MS article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/virtualization/restored-hyper-v-virtual-machines-not-start#resolution - tried all, VM can be powered on after Deleting saved state but live migrations won't work without "reboot" of the machine..

Any ideas?

thank you!

I already tried CPU compatibility feature turned on, no luck.
Also, there is no ISO file mounted on the VM. All three hosts has the same network adapter name.
Hosts has Windows 2019 Standard installed.

Found MS article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/virtualization/restored-hyper-v-virtual-machines-not-start#resolution